# javascript loop with delay code fix

Tags: javascript

how to fix this code as per

[How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop).

it still gets executed without delay .

```
const spkz = responsiveVoice.speak;
let azj = ['hi', 'hello', 'how are ya'];
var i = 1; //  set your counter to 1

function myLoop() { //  create a loop function

  azj.forEach((item, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => { //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
      alert(item); //  your code here
      i++; //  increment the counter
      if (i < index) { //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
        myLoop(); //  ..  again which will trigger another 
      } //  ..  setTimeout()
    }, 10000)
  })

}

myLoop();
```

Comment: use ``setTimeout()``

Comment: already using setTimeout() once the loop gets executed there is no delaying it. => prob.

Comment: each iteration starts a setTimeout immediately, so, you can't pause javascript like that

Comment: this one says its possible . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: @Isquare But there is no loop in the accepted answer.

Comment: `this one says its possible` - there is no forEach in that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "pause" javascript like that. a `setTimout` is asynchronous, meaning it will not block synchronous code from running, so when you run any kind of "for" loop, it will call all the `setTimeouts` at once.

You can make a manual loop like this and delay it with recursion:

```js
let azj = ['hi', 'hello', 'how are ya'];
var i = 0;

function myLoop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(azj[i])
    i++
    
    if (i < azj.length) {
      myLoop()
    }
  }, 3000)
}

myLoop();
```

For more information, check out [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3583740/4937981)

Comment: thanks this one seems to work

Comment: @Isquare Because it's the exact same code as in the answer you've mentioned in your question...

Comment: @Andreas Sorry! I should've linked to the answer instead. I didn't realize the answer in the linked question was identical to this.

Comment: i will flag it duplicate / delete the qn .. i shoulda took a closer look at it.

Comment: @Isquare Do not delete the question. Flag it as a duplicate, that's what it's for.

Comment: ok . already flagged it as dup.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use `forEach` inside the loop function. Instead, you can access the array items using `azj[i]`